# About iOS deprecated api and SDKs

Tags: ios, api, deprecated

About deprecated api and SDKs

UIAlertview is available from iOS 2.0 to iOS 9.0. From iOS 8.0 .XCode will warn that use UIAlertController instead.
But when i set base sdk as iOS 10.3 and set deployment target as iOS 7.1, the app will run from iOS 7.1 to iOS 10.3 devices succefully.
And when  set base sdk as iOS 10.3 and set deployment target as iOS 10.0, the app also run successfully ,just have many warning ,but build successfully.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. But bad practice to use deprecated things. Use UIAlertController instead.
 Some day it maybe won't work. who knows about Apple's decisions.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your Message." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: Strangly, low version iOS run high version api will crash, conversely the app will run successfully ，though there are many warnning

Comment: @kscorpio Lower versions of iOS will crash when using newer API methods because they don't know about them, on the other hand newer API versions do also know the methods from lower versions to prevent apps from crashing after an iOS update. They just get marked as deprecated to tell the developers to change to the newer one (the warnings you're seeing).